# Tools for designing a web interface

Tags: user-interface, graphics, webview, designer

In my case web design and programming are becoming increasingly overlapping. I've mostly used Twitter bootstrap to design web interfaces for applications I've built. But, in my opinion it is rather an appliance that consists of ready interface parts to use. Oftentimes, web interfaces require some individual features, customisations etc. As the time goes I feel like I'd like to deliver better user experience and appearance of web pages I build. Having said that, I think I would need to perform following actions:

- designing logos, icons, buttons, menus, backgrounds, clickable elements, like arrows for navigating, collapsing/expanding menus
- because of mobile devices oftentimes the aforementioned elements will need to be resized in order to fit a particular resolution

Note, that I almost won't have anything to do with manipulating images. (I mean of course images will need to be resized before served to a device with a particular resolution, but I guess that is not an use case for Photoshop or similar programs.)

**I'd like to know what tool would be suitable for this purpose.**

I've been thinking about Photoshop and Illustrator, where Illustrator seems to be winning, because it is said to be able to create vector-based graphics that can be easily scaled and reused. However, Photoshop  is claimed to be an industry standard and everything necessary for web design can be done with it.

I don't need any drag-and-drop graphics generating tool or something that would generate code for me, I  can write HTML and CSS myself.

Answer (score 0):

For designing logos, menus, buttons and other graphic elements, you have to use the pen tool and draw shapes tools.

If you ask me to choose one among Photoshop and Illustrator, I recommend Photoshop for simple graphic elements like buttons and menus. Illustrator is for more high end graphics, like background image graphics, illustrations and logos.

However, you have to gain some basic knowledge of pen tools, shapes tools, and in Illustrator, the path finder, mesh tool and gradient tools before you start.